# Apollo GraphQL variable argument name

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

**Background:** I have built a data grid with cell editing on the frontend. Everytime you edit a field in a cell, it is instantly updated on the server. So I thought it would be a good practice to only submit that single field in my mutation. This would reduce network traffic size and the backend would process the update faster (this is all optimization on a very high level of course).

This means the argument that I send with my GraphQL mutation is variable. You can very nicely inject argument values through GraphQL variables, but what is a good way for the keys?

To visualize the problem, this is something I'd wish for:

```
mutation($id: 1, $field: "first_name", $value: "John") {
    updateClient(
        id: $id,
        $field: $value
    ) {
        id
    }
}
```

Comment: simply pass a single 'changes' object `{key:value, key2:value2}` - iterate over props to construct DB query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately argument names cannot be variable in a query. The convention is to use an input object type for mutations to circumvent this problem:

```
type Mutation {
    updateClient(id: ID!, input: ClientInput!): Client
}
input ClientInput {
    a: String
    b: Number
    …
}
```

(instead of `updateClient(id: ID!, a: String, b: Number, …)`)

With this pattern, you can pass an object of type `ClientInput` to your mutation as the argument:

```
query(`mutation($id: ID!, $input: ClientInput!) {
    updateClient(id: $id, input: $input) {
        id
    }
}`, {id: 1, input: {["first_name"]: "John"}})
```

I really wish there was some kind of argument spread syntax in GraphQL to make this nesting unncessary.

Comment: That already looks fantastic! Thank you very much, I would never have thought of this approach and I do not think it's too bad :)

Comment: With `id` as a separate parameter, it's okay-ish, but if you place the `id: ID!` in the `ClientInput` as well, and every mutation field will have only one single parameter named `input`, it's more obvious that there is something wrong with it.